# Sharing hw resources with more blades

Tags: server, cluster-computing, vmware, virtualization

In my architecture I have two blades in a cluster, let's say with a CPU of 32 cores.
All the blades have several VMs managed by vCenter.
I want to install a VM for a software that require at least 40 cores of CPU to run without problems.
Are the resources of the two blades shared and so I can install the VM forgetting of the individual blade hw details?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to create a VM with more CPUs than the underlying hardware has logical processors.